# Display Product Prices for specific product in Shopify

Tags: php, html, shopify, liquid

[image]

I am currently trying to display prices for all my products in my shopify store. I have managed to show this for my first product using the following code:

```
<div class="grid__item">
{% for collection in collections %}



    {% for product in collection.products %}
   {% for variant in product.variants %}


{% if forloop.index <=1 %}
<div id="temp_first" style="display:none;">
<div class="style14">Style</div>
<div class="style11">(No)</div>
<div class="front"><img src="//files/front.jpg?v=1473520767" title="1 Sided Full Color" /></div>
<div class="reverse"><img src="//1/1265/7581/files/reverse.jpg?v=1473520807" title="1 Sided Only" /></div>
<div class="price"><a href="/products/leaflets?variant={{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.price | money | remove: '.00'}}</a></div>

{% elsif forloop.index <7 %}
<div class="price"><a href="/products/leaflets?variant={{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.price | money | remove: '.00'}}</a></div>

{% elsif forloop.index <10 %} 
<div class="price2"><a href="/products/leaflets?variant={{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.price | money | remove: '.00'}}</a></div>

{% elsif forloop.index <13 %} 
<div class="price3"><a href="/products/leaflets?variant={{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.price | money | remove: '.00'}}</a></div>

{% elsif forloop.index ==13 %}
<div class="price3"><a href="/products/leaflets?variant={{ variant.id }}">{{ variant.price | money | remove: '.00'}}</a></div>
</div>
{% endif %}

   {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}


{% endfor %}
```

Now that works perfectly fine. The problem I have now is that I would like to display prices for a 2nd product and I duplicated the above code and changed the links in order to link this to the correct product page and variant and this works fine. The issue is the prices that are shown are for the first product and I don't know what I need to change in the code to target the 2nd product. Whether this is by its handle name or what, i'm just not sure, hence the need for some help.

If somebody could please advise, how I could target the 2nd product, would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can get an arbitrary product variable using the following syntax:

`{% assign custom_product = all_products['product-handle'] %}`
(where 'product-handle' would be replaced with the handle of the product that you want to grab).

This can be done dynamically:

```
{% assign some_handle = 'product-handle' %}
{% assign custom_product = all_products[some_handle] %}
```

If you had some attribute of the main product that said what the secondary product would be (such as a metafield that was set either using an app or the Shopify FD browser extension), you could reference it something like this:

```
{% assign some_handle = product.metafields.custom_namespace.related_product %}
{% assign custom_product = all_products[some_handle] %}
```

The variable custom_product in any of the examples above is a variable representing the appropriate product at this point, so we can reference any product properties for that product exactly the same way as we would for the main product.  For example:

```
<h3>{{ product.title }} is {{ product.price | money }}, but {{ custom_product.title }} is {{ custom_product.price | money }}</h3>
```

PS - Additionally, you can use `{{ variant.price | money_without_trailing_zeros }}` instead of chaining the money and remove filters.

PPS - Looking at your original code again, note that you can save yourself some headaches by making your links dynamic: `<a href="/products/{{ product.handle }}?variant={{ variant.id }}">`

PPPS - Your code as-written is trying to loop through every variant in every product in every collection.  Depending on how big your product list is, this may not work - Shopify has a hard upper limit on how many products are returned for a collection when you're not paginating.  Depending on what exactly you're trying to accomplish, you may be able to better take advantage of the Liquid templating language to get everything working in a more succinct and manageable way. :)

---

***EXAMPLE*** (following original poster's clarification)

If you're creating a number of grids to display in the background of your page, what about something like this?

```
<div class="product_grid_container">
{% for custom_product in collection.products %}
  <div class="price_grid" data-product-id="{{ custom_product.id }}" data-index="{{ forloop.index }}">
    <a href="/products/{{ custom_product.handle }}">{{ custom_product.title }}</a>
    <!-- Any other header information here -->
    {% for variant in custom_product.variants %}
    <!-- Logic/structure for displaying variants for the product in the grid here. If it's complicated, you might want to move it to a separate snippet and then use an include statement. -->
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

This will produce a distinct HTML grid for each of the products that you care about, and you can then use CSS rules to position/style them appropriately.

Does this get you closer to what you're after?

Comment: Thanks Dave B for your response. I am currently trying to display prices for 18 products that I have and managed to do the first product which had a total of 66 variants. This was something I was unsure of, as I am currently displaying prices on a page as need the prices to be displayed within a grid and then using to link to the specific product page.

Comment: Would it work to make a collection with those specific 18 products?  Then you would `{% assign super_collection = collections['collection name'] %}` and loop through the products just in that one collection.

Comment: If you could describe what you're trying to do in a little bit more detail I might be able to give you a more relevant solution :)

Comment: Thanks Dave B, i will edit the main question by adding an image, that will show prices for a specific product. What I have is a page with a background image of the grids and I have only placed the prices on top of the page. The issue is that I have 18 different grids to fill as this is a page where all product prices are displayed and a customer just has to click the price which will then take the customer to the product page where the quantity and style dropdowns will be prefilled by the selections.

Comment: Thanks DaveB, would i need to add anything in the prices page in order to call anything, as added this code to my page.prices.liquid but nothing shows up...

Comment: Ah! Sorry-  I accidentally used product in collection instead of product in collection.products.  Serves me right for writing without properly testing!  Fixed the above example.

Comment: Simple demo based on the above: http://bold19.myshopify.com/collections/frontpage?view=pricegrids

Comment: Thanks Dave B, silly question is the above query been amended?

Comment: Apologies as pasted this in my pages.prices.liquid but my page shows up blank. I'm guessing I don't have to do add anything within the page so maybe need to check my product handles..

Comment: I have added the initial 
{% for collection in collections %}
    {% for product in collection.products %}
   {% for variant in product.variants %} and can see prices, thank you!

Comment: Hi Dave B, it is, just having issues with displaying it lol. At the moment, as i have so many variants, the variant option is repeating after every price so trying to sort it out.

Comment: Hm.  Yeah, if there's a lot of products/variants the screen could get pretty crowded. You could maybe use CSS to set a max-height and an overflow (hidden or scroll) property on the enclosing container; or maybe add a truncation condition to the variant loop (something like `{% if forloop.index > 10 %}<a href='/products/{{ product.handle }}'>See more</a>{% break %}{% endif %}`

Comment: Thanks Dave B, will try that.. would be good if i could share the page, unfortunately have a password set on the page, which i can share but prob not a good idea to post it on here lol

Comment: hi, dave b, for some reason I have duplicate variants showing as I have multiple prices for multiple quantities. I want to create a list / array which stores 1 of each variant. This is what i currently have:
{% assign result = array[1] %}
    {% for variant in custom_product.variants %}
     {% unless result contains variant.option1 %}
         {% capture result %}{{ variant.option1 }}{% endcapture %}
     {% endunless %}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ result }}

{% endfor %}
Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Are you using an app to handle the multiple prices for different quantities, or are you doing those manually? If you're using an app, there's probably something that you can look for that flags whether a variant is a clone of a base variant.  If that's the case, you can put something like the following at the beginning of your variant loop: `{% if [condition] %}{% continue %}{% endif %}` (where the condition would be replaced by what your app looks for. Eg: `variant.metafields.inventory.hidden == "true"`)

Comment: If you're not using an app, you might be able to figure out some kind of condition check based on some other piece of data that you're using. For example, if all of your price break variants end with `(#)` (where `#` is some number), you could use something like this: `{% assign qty_level = variant.title | split: ' ' | last | remove: '(' | remove: ')' | times: 1 %}  {% if qty_level > 1 %}{% continue %}{% endif %}`